# notification service clear button disable in android

Tags: android

when i run my application i am running one notification service .how i disable clear notification service button in my application only i need to run the service when my application is running .is there any way to disable the clear notification button .please

help me

Thanks

Aswan

Answer (score 1):

The `Button` class inherits the `setClickable(boolean)` method from `View`. if you set it to false, the `Button` will be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple, just add FLAG_NO_CLEAR flags to your notification object.
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;